# SQLAlchemy 'on_conflict_do_update' does not update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code which I would like to do an upsert:

```
def add_electricity_reading(
    *, period_usage, period_started_at, is_estimated, customer_pk
):
    from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

    values = dict(
        customer_pk=customer_pk,
        period_usage=period_usage,
        period_started_at=period_started_at,
        is_estimated=is_estimated,
    )
    insert_stmt = insert(ElectricityMeterReading).values(**values)
    do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint=ElectricityMeterReading.__table_args__[0].name,
        set_=dict(
            period_usage=period_usage,
            period_started_at=period_started_at,
            is_estimated=is_estimated,
        )
    )
    conn = DBSession.connection()
    conn.execute(do_update_stmt)

    return DBSession.query(ElectricityMeterReading).filter_by(**dict(
        period_usage=period_usage,
        period_started_at=period_started_at,
        customer_pk=customer_pk,
        is_estimated=is_estimated,
    )).one()

 def test_updates_existing_record_for_started_at_if_already_exists():
    started_at = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    existing = add_electricity_reading(
        period_usage=0.102,
        customer_pk=customer.pk,
        period_started_at=started_at,
        is_estimated=True,
    )
    started_at = existing.period_started_at
    reading = add_electricity_reading(
        period_usage=0.200,
        customer_pk=customer.pk,
        period_started_at=started_at,
        is_estimated=True,
    )

    # existing record was updated
    assert reading.period_usage == 0.200
    assert reading.id == existing.id
```

In my test when I add an existing record with `period_usage=0.102` and then execute the query again but change to `period_usage=0.2`. When the final query at the bottom returns the record the period_usage is still 0.102.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Have you fetched that `ElectricityMeterReading` instance before the update in that same session?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes the SELECT query at the bottom will have ran the first time when i added the period_usage=123 initial record

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] of how you're doing it? If I understood you correctly, then the problem is that SQLA checks if the entities returned by the final query already reside in the current session (based on primary key) and gives you back the existing instance. Since you're using a "manual" bulk insert/update (compared to using for example `Query.update()` with synchronization), the session is not aware of the changes you've made.

Comment: @IljaEverilä added to the first post

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is explained in "Session Basics" under ["What does the Session do?"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do) The session holds references to objects it has loaded in a structure called the [identity map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html), and so ensures that only 1 unique object per primary key value exists at a time during a session's lifetime. You can verify this with the following assertion in your own code:

```
assert existing is reading
```

The [Core](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) insert (or update) statements you are executing do not keep the session in sync with the changes taking place in the database the way for example [`Query.update()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update) does. In order to fetch the new values you can [expire](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expire) the ORM loaded state of the unique object:

```
DBSession.expire(existing)  # or reading, does not matter

# existing record was updated
assert reading.period_usage == 0.200
assert reading.id == existing.id
```